# Orientation SAP UI5 sap.m.IconTabBar

Tags: sapui5, tabbar

I just wondered if there's a way to centralize the sap.m.IconTabBar. So that the icons don't start straight on the left but they are all central. The icons should take the whole length of the sap.m.IconTabBar.

Is there any possibility or no way to adapt the orientation?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is no property in the IconTabBar control which would allow you to center align the selection Icons. But it is achievable with some CSS trickery.

If you assign a text-align: center property to the container of the selections they will align to the center, as each of the child div's being inline-block elements.

XML:

```
<IconTabBar
        class="tabbedBar"
...
...
```

CSS:

```
.tabbedBar .sapMITBHead{
    text-align:center;
}
```